# page load if Repeater eval lable text = then add cssclass to closet div

Tags: javascript, css, .net, vb.net, repeater

I am trying to on add class on page load If lable1.text <> date.now, then add class    `hidden` to div with class   `ui red ribbon label`  .
Should I use Javasript?
I am a beginner and please help me in solving this issue.

```
                            <div style="top: 10px;" class="ui red ribbon label "> new </div>

                            <div class="row w3-text-black w3-center" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 40px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("newdate") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just do something along the lines of:

```
<div style="top: 10px;" class='<%Response.Write(IIf(lable1.text <> date.now, "ui red ribbon label", "hidden")) %>'> new </div>
```